# How to get COUNTIF to validate cell is unique properly in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is my configuration:

[image]

And yet here I am getting an error when I shouldn't be. That is, "suffer" only appears once in the entire document, yet it is flagged as invalid:

[image]

How do I fix this?

```
=COUNTIF($C:$C,"="&C2) < 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cell to compare (in your formula **C2**) must be address of first cell of formatted range (in your example with range **Sheet1!C1:C8205** it is **C1**).

Please try `=COUNTIF($C:$C,"="&C1) < 2`